# When i perform wudu it feels a bubble passed through vagina. So it invalidate my wudu or should I continue?

Tags: wudu, taharah

Whenever i perform ablution sometimes during ablution or in salah i felt a bubble passed through vagina. Is this invalidate my wudu'?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help].

Answer (score 1):

The 4 major Sunni Fiqh scholars differed in this situation.
Shafee and Ibn Hanbal said that it does invalidate and you should redo wudu'.
Malik and Abu hanifa said that no, wind coming out from front does not invalidate wudu'.

And as in all situations where there is a difference between the 4 scholars, one may either choose the easier opinion or the safer opinion, both are right.

Allah knows best.

https://islamqa.info/en/176951

Comment: This answer could benefit from some elaboration to be more useful!

Comment: @Medi1Saif can you help me make my answers better? by explaining exactly what to do?

Comment: The answer actually directly answers the question that's fine. What you may do to make it better is share an insight of the discussion: X said it is this way because ... while Y said it is not because ... Also try to avoid islamqa we don't want to be a copy-paste forum for any site! It is better to quote from the sources than from fatwas. Also check in our Meta [1](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324/do-we-want-cut-and-paste-answers) and [2](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3001/how-is-it-effecting-us-as-a-community-when-90-of-the-answers-are-refering-to-on)

Comment: Thanks you that was pretty helpful. I will be sure not to be a copy-paste, quote from sources directly, and present my answer as a discussion.